# Object Rotated by accelerometer doesn't collide properly in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, accelerometer, collision, rigid-bodies

First of all, I want to make clear that this is NOT a duplicate of this Question: [unity 3d rotate the gameobject according to accelerometer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25358042/unity-3d-rotate-the-gameobject-according-to-accelerometer)

So, i have managed to rotate an object in unity by using the accelerometer & compass. This works fine normally but, when another object collides with it, it clips through the object which results in the object moving randomly.

I realized that this was due to the fact that i was **directly** altering the transform of the object. I know that I am not supposed to directly modify the transform and that i should use the rigidBody instead but, I don't know how I can change it to where it doesn't directly alter the transform.

Here is how i currently rotate the object:

```
float norm=0f;
Rigidbody rb;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();


}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    Input.compass.enabled = true;
    if (norm == 0) {
        norm = Input.compass.trueHeading;
    }
    float val=Input.compass.trueHeading-norm;


    transform.rotation=Quaternion.Euler( new Vector3 ( (Input.acceleration.y-1)*90,val ,0));
    transform.Rotate (Input.acceleration.x*90*transform.forward);

}
```

So how could I change this so that I don't directly alter the Transform?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the [Documentation for `Rigidbody.MoveRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html).  It will rotate your `RigidBody` towards the given rotation while "*complying with the Rigidbody's interpolation setting.*"

As a note: When you're working directly with physics objects you should be using `FixedUpdate()`, not `Update()`. If you're unsure why, they cover the differences in the [Unity Tutorials](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/update-and-fixedupdate). TL;DR It runs in a simulated "fixed framerate frame."